# executable with py2exe is not working console is closing

Tags: python, py2exe

Hey guys I am trying to convert my skript to an executable with py2exe. I can can convert the same script with pyinstaller, but I would like to learn why is it not working with py2exe.

My code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob as glob

x = input(r'')
os.chdir(x)
files = glob.glob("*.nc")
print(files)

for file in files: 
    print(file)
    ds = xarray.open_dataset(file)
    name = file.split('.')
    df = ds.to_dataframe()
    df.to_csv(name[0] + '.txt', sep ='\t')
```

This file calls: Convert_nc_to_txt.py

Now I wrote an script to convert like described in: https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/blob/master/docs/py2exe.freeze.md

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from py2exe import freeze


freeze(
    console=['Convert_nc_to_txt.py'],
    data_files=None,
    zipfile='library.zip',
    options={"py2exe":{"excludes":["scipy"],"includes":["xarray","pandas","glob"]}})
```

This file calls: setup.py

I am converting on cmd with `python setup.py py2exe`.

After I enter the path, the console closes immediately.

I do not get any errors or can see them.

Does someone have any idea?

best

Comment: Maybe `files` is empty ... insert a `_ = input('...')` in front of the for-loop to see `print(files)`'s output.

Comment: I strongly recommend `auto-py-to-exe` for generating .exe-files - works like a charm. You can find it on PyPi or on github.